# GWT converting current date to GMT

Tags: gwt, gmt, datetime-conversion

I am converting the current date to GMT time.

The result is in-consistent, due to this my date time calculations are going worng.

```
            DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            String gmtStr = new Date().toGMTString().replace("GMT", "").trim();
            long deptime= depTime - df.parse(gmtStr).getTime();
            deptime = deptime / 1000;
            seconds = (deptime % 60);
            minutes = (deptime % 3600) / 60;
            hours = (deptime / 3600);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the best way is, but you could use the `getTimezoneOffsert`:

```
final Date gmtDate = new Date();
final Date offDate = new Date(gmtDate.getTime() + gmtDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
```

The `offDate` when displayed with `DateTimeFormat.getFormat(PredefinedFormat.DATE_TIME_LONG)`  will still show the utc/gmt offset, because basically you have create a new time in the current timezone, but it matches the time of the GMT time and the long value returned from `getTime()` will be the number of milliseconds you can use in your calculation.